# mongodb (aggregation) - $lookup with the lookup result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i am new in aggregation framework and have the following problem/question.

My collections looks like this:

**users**

```
    _id: ObjectId('604caef28aa89e769585f0c4')
    baseData: { 
       firstName: "max"
       username: "max_muster"
       ...
       ...
    }
```

**activitiesFeed**

```
    _id: ObjectId('604cb97c99bbd77b54047370')
    userID: "604caef28aa89e769585f0c4"     // the user id 
    activity: "604caf718aa89e769585f0c8"   // the activity id 
    viewed: false
```

**activities**

```
  _id: ObjectId('604caf718aa89e769585f0c8')
 "baseData": {
      "userID":"604caef28aa89e769585f0c4",
      "type":0,
      "title":"Alessandro send you a friend request.",
      "description":"",
      "actionID":"604caef28aa89e769585f0c4"
   },
```

**aggregate function**

```
const response = ActivityFeed.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { userID: ObjectId(args.user) },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'activities',
          localField: 'activity',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'lookup_activities',
        },
      },
      { $unwind: '$activities' },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'lookup_activities.baseData.actionID',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'lookup_users',
        },
      },
    ]);
```

How i can made a lookup with the first lookup result?

I made a lookup to the activities collection. This collection holds the id for the second lookup baseData.userID. But with this approach i have no result with the second lookup.

The reason why i made a join to the activities collection is that the actionID can hold a userID or a document id from another collection. It depend on the type in the activities collection.

Is it in the aggregation framework possible to made a lookup which depends on the type and of the previous lookup?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

All I did is fixing your aggregation. You unwind the wrong field and please make sure all your ID fields are ObjectId. I highly recommend using [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) to assist your aggregation if you are new to the aggregation function. They have stage by stage assistance GUI which will really make your life easier.

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XKtrGDPWtOM)

```
db.activitiesFeed.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userID: ObjectId("604caef28aa89e769585f0c4")
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "activities",
      localField: "activity",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "lookup_activities",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$lookup_activities"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "lookup_activities.baseData.actionID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "lookup_users",
    },
  },
])
```

Sample Used

```
 db={
  "users": [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("604caef28aa89e769585f0c4"),
      baseData: {
        firstName: "max",
        username: "max_muster"
      }
    }
  ],
  "activitiesFeed": [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("604cb97c99bbd77b54047370"),
      userID: ObjectId("604caef28aa89e769585f0c4"),
      activity: ObjectId("604caf718aa89e769585f0c8"),
      viewed: false
    }
  ],
  "activities": [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("604caf718aa89e769585f0c8"),
      "baseData": {
        "userID": ObjectId("604caef28aa89e769585f0c4"),
        "type": 0,
        "title": "Alessandro send you a friend request.",
        "description": "",
        "actionID": ObjectId("604caef28aa89e769585f0c4")
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It works perfect for me :D Thank you @Koodies
Do you know if it is possible to change the loopup result?

The result is baseData{ ..... } is it possible to remove the baseData that the result is only the keys ?

Comment: Yes, please look at $project or $set